# Does Node run out of http handles if used thusly

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, https

In Express I have a route that makes an http call to Amazon S3 to see if a specific image exists or not (it's basically a proxy call to bypass my inability to make a cross-domain call directly to Amazon from the browser).

The problem is that it works successively for a while and then suddenly just stops and is only fixed by my restarting my express app.

Just in case (though I believe the code is totally generic) here's the code:

```
Router.get('/testS3Image',
  function(request, response){
    try{
      var imagePath = request.param('imagePath');
      var https = require('https');


  var options = { 
    method:'GET',
    host: 's3.amazonaws.com',  
    path: '/' + imagePath,
    port: 443
  };

  console.log("MAKING S3 call with options " + JSON.stringify(options));
  var req = https.request(options, 
    function(res) {
      try{
        if(!res || !res.headers || !res.headers["content-length"])
          throw ("image not found on S3");
        console.log("returned from S3 call with success");
        response.json({success:true,headers:res.headers});            
      }catch(e){
        console.log("returned from S3 call with failure");
        response.json({success:false, error:e});            
      }
    }
  );
  req.end();
}catch(e){
}
```

});

after the `https.request()` call is made, nothing happens. It simply goes dark.  I'm new enough to Node to not know how I can follow along to see what's happening beneath the hood.  We're running this in nginx.

Since it works perfectly for a long time and then suddenly breaks with no obvious rhyme or reason I am suspecting some sort of http call limitation, but I am unclear on what I can do differently.

Comment: You could take some heap snapshots and see if you can see anything in particular that might be unintentionally accumulating.

Answer (score 0):

You're not reading the response data from S3; I wonder if this is causing the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying I need to actually consume the data stream in order for this to not clog up the works? If so, can you point me to some documentation on this because it would be a very important revelation on how this works beneath the hood. I thought that I can basically ignore any data item and it just gets cleaned up.

Comment: The `https.request()` example in the [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) sets up a data handler that dumps everything to the console; you could do the the same in your `https.request()` callback but (for now) drop the data on the floor.

(I assume at some point you'll want to actually stream the S3 data back to the client connected to your server...)